# Changing On-Click Button Color in Kivy

Tags: python, button, kivy

I'm using Kivy with Python 2.7.  I am familiar with how to alter the color of the static button itself, but how do you change the color of the button when you press it? The default is blue.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [reference for `Button`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.button.html#kivy.uix.button.Button.background_down), the property `background_down` stores the path to an image used for the background while the `Button` is pressed. This is the default:

```
background_down = StringProperty(
    'atlas://data/images/defaulttheme/button_pressed')
```

You can change that property to point to a different [image or`atlas`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.atlas.html).

Answer (score 1):

The Kivy framework uses background images for button_normal and button_down, which the background_color only tints, so this in the kv language might not behave how you'd expect:

```
<Button>:    
    background_color: 1, 0, 0  # Tints the button red
    background_normal: 'images/button_normal.png'  # A clear image gives a bright red. 
    background_down: 'images/button_down.png'  # A gray image gives a duller red.
    border: (2, 2, 2, 2)  # Don't stretch the outer two pixels on each edge when resizing.
```

This style lets you have say a dull border and bright inner and swap them round on the button press.If you use this system though, images will be imported with colours ignored. To fix this and solve your problem remove the background_color:

```
<Button>:    
    background_normal: 'images/button_normal.png'  # Eg. A red button
    background_down: 'images/button_down.png'  # Eg. A green button
    border: (2, 2, 2, 2)  # Don't stretch the outer two pixels on each edge when resizing.
```

That'll change the colour of the buttons to whatever you've made in the image. It's worth noting that Kivy is excellent at stretching the images out, so if you have single colour buttons or tiny borders, you only need a tiny image, I use 8x8 pixels.